# Accessing Azure blob from airflow

Tags: azure, airflow

I am continuously facing issues while establishing connection from airflow to azure blob. Please find the approaches that I followed,

1. **Using Service Principal:** Updated following details in connection,

- Account Name: https:<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/
- Blob Storage Login:
- Blob Storage Key:
- Tenant Id (Active Directory Auth):

2. **Using SAS Token**:

- Blob Storage Login: <storage_account_name>
- SAS Token:

For all these connection establishment, it ends up in the error 'blank error' while testing the connection.

[image: Airflow Error Screenshot]

When I run the dag, it end up with error Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known.

To add more information on this, azure storage account is only enabled from selected network and endpoint. Airflow is in same vnet and service principal also has storage blob contributor access as well. Not sure how to proceed from here.

I validated access from another azure storage account. It is working but only storage account that I am not able to access is my original one. Not sure what is the issue. I know it is something in storage account. But unable to find the root cause.

Comment: Have you tried to use just <storage_account_name> for Account Name? (no "https:/" / ".blob.core.windows.net/")?

Comment: I tried it just now, and it ended up with same error. Thank you!